# Encryption Algorithm without special characters

Tags: encryption, coldfusion

Is there an encryption algorithm in ColdFusion that doesn't use any special characters (only alphanumeric)?  I have some data that I am passing to a user as a pseudo password which includes their username and the site that they are assigned to.  I need to encrypt the string with an encryption algorithm built into ColdFusion 8 Enterprise edition and it cannot have any special characters in the final string.  Is this possible and if so what algorithm will do this?

```
<cfset loc.token = encrypt(loc.token,Application.secretKey,'Blowfish','Base64') />
```

Comment: Just encode the result in base-64!

Comment: It already is in base64 :) ie That is what the fourth parameter does ie sets the encoding of the output string

Comment: @Leigh: D'oh, indeed -- I was careless and just thought "ASCII printable", but he really wants only alphanumerics. Sorry!

Comment: @Kerrek SB - No worries. I was not thinking hex at first either.

Comment: If you want something with more characters than hex, there's also [Douglas Crockford's base32 encoding](http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use binhex.  Encode each byte as a hexadecimal number, ranging from 00 to FF.  Base 64, however, includes several nonalphanumeric characters, such as + / = .

Comment: Right - binhex is a 4-bit, base-64 is 6-bit encoding. Whatever floats your boat. For truely alphanumeric output binhex is indeed better.

Comment: Well, we can come up with a compromise: Base32, which is a 5-bit encoding, though this is presumably less well known than binhex or Base 64

Comment: Nice. Though it still seems to include `=` for padding :-( Or do you mean `base32hex`? How about [Crockford's Base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#Crockford.27s_Base32), which disallows accidental obscenity? (Presumably invented on expertsexchange.com.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB - +1. Haha. I did not know about the excluded letters. @Peter O - Good idea. In CF it is just a matter of changing the encoding parameter to "hex" ie `encrypt(text, key, algorithm, encoding)`

Comment: If I changed the Base64 argument of the function to "hex" it worked perfectly with no special characters.

Comment: @Kerreck - it says that standardized base32 has "optional" padding, though I must admit that it might be hard to find an encoder/decoder that supports unpadded base32.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you,

```
#encrypt('text_im_encrypting', ToBase64(BinaryDecode('my_encrypt_key',"Hex")), 'AES', 'Hex');#
```

replace the *text_im_encrypting* and *my_encrypt_key* values obviously...   =)

Answer (score -1):

There are two undocumented functions, cfusion_encrypt(string, key) and cfusion_decrypt(string, key), that encrypt/decrypt based on hexadecimal strings. So essentially, since the resulting string is completely hex, it contains no special characters:

```
<cfscript>
    writeoutput(cfusion_encrypt("stackoverflow", "rocks")); // outputs 011B0208181D190619151E0014
    writeoutput(cfusion_decrypt("011B0208181D190619151E0014", "rocks")); // outputs stackoverflow
</cfscript>
```

Comment: That is not the same. It does not use the "Blowfish" algorithm.

Comment: @Leigh: Did you read the question? He didn't ask for a blowfish algorithm - he asked for an algorithm that didn't return any special characters.

Comment: What I meant was, I think you misunderstood the question. He asked about an *algorithm* for the `encrypt` function. So `cfusion_encrypt` probably is not what he is looking for (it also does not provide real/strong encryption). All that is needed is to use `encrypt(text, key, algorithm, "hex")` and no more special characters.